# How to see UTXOs at a script

Tags: utxo, library

I am creating a function that takes in UTXOs at a script as a parameter. I know there is a function Plutus.Contract.utxoAt but how do i see what that will return ? I am still developing out my script and it is not on the chain yet.I need to see what utxoAt will return in order to pass it in to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a map containing the TxOutRefs of the provided address. Perhaps these are what you want your script to validate? Unless I'm misunderstanding your intention, you can't use these contract functions onchain. They are useful for offchain actions such as inspecting and building transactions.

Comment: Yeah , turns out I can just put that in a print statement and run it in playground. I’ll be able to see what it returns in the log.